# Is it possible to set selected the header of a grouped listview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using a listview in xamarin forms with GroupDisplayBinding, and i am populating it with events of different dates, the headers are dates, as a date can contain many events, i have a ToDay button that when i click it, the list should jump to the current date if i scroll down or up in the events, is that possible ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the ScrollTo method of the ListView. Pass in your group object and the desired position and animated values.

```
public void ScrollTo (Object item, ScrollToPosition position, Boolean animated)
```